# Cocoa bindings -- trying to bind the state of an NSMenuItem to my custom BOOL

Tags: cocoa, macos, cocoa-bindings, nsmenuitem

In my mac app, [Model m] is a custom object with a synthesized BOOL property and ivar rollAnimations.  And animationsItem is an NSMenuItem object.  I want to bind the state of my animationsItem to the rollAnimations property and ivar of [Model m].  A two-way binding would be ideal (so that changing either property changes the other), but if that's messy (retain cycles and such), I'll settle for a one-way binding, such that changing the menu item changes the rollAnimations property.

Here is a code snippet.  It's not working.  What am I missing?

```
NSMutableDictionary *bindingOptions = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
NSNumber *yesNumber = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
[bindingOptions setObject:yesNumber forKey:NSValidatesImmediatelyBindingOption];
[animationsItem bind:@"state" toObject:[Model m] withKeyPath:@"rollAnimations" options:bindingOptions];
```

Comment: You can simplify the construction of the dictionary using `[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:forKey:]`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[The Cocoa Bindings Reference](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CocoaBindingsRef/) lists [all the bindings a menu item supports](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CocoaBindingsRef/BindingsText/NSMenuItem.html). The one you want is `@"value"`, not `@"state"`. ([This goes for buttons, too](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CocoaBindingsRef/BindingsText/NSButton.html), by the way.)